# xcode simulator iphone screen size

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I put this code in my app:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
NSLog(@"screenWidth : %f", screenWidth);
NSLog(@"screenHeight : %f", screenHeight);
```

The I start the simulator with Iphone 3.5 inch. 
The log prints 320.000000 for the width.

However, when I then change the device for the simulator, selecing 4inch, it stills shows the same width. Why? Whats wrong. It is supposed to be 640 px in width for Iphone 4 and above, doesnt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no the width is always 320 POINTS / DPIs -- what you mean is that it really has 640 PIXELS (which are device dependant)

Calculations are always based on device INDEPENDENT points

UIScreen offers a scalingFactor that translates dpi <> pixels

Comment: Well, please can you help me understand this? Im trying to position image and text inside a uibutton. I need to position them at X-position. Is the x position coordinate for POINTS or PIXEL?

Comment: So I dont need to care about different iphone sizes when positioning buttons with CGRectMake? I can always think that the x goes from 0 to 320? is that what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. The only thing to remember is that 3.5 is 480 height while 4 is 568 height

Answer (score 1):

In the simulator screenWidth will be always 320 ( right now iphone4-5 ). You can check the scale with [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

scale will be 2.0 if you running on retina iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/scale), that value is the "default logical value". If you want to know the actual size, take a look at `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]`. For retina devices, this value is `2.0`, so do `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]`